# How did we find Vin in this CMOS?

Tags: transistors, cmos, nmos, pmos

Why did the lecturer decided that Vin is vGSn - vGSp + vDD , Why did he not go through the drain path and used vGDn and vGDp ?
[image]

Comment: ... Probably because vGDn is equal to vGDp...

Comment: Probably because Vgs is the voltage that controls the channel.

Answer (score 1):

You can if you want.

$$V_{in} = V_{GDn}+V_{DpG}+V_{GSn}$$
But Dn and Dp are equal. They both are same potential point.
$$\implies V_{in}= V_{GDn} +V_{DpG}+V_{GSn}$$
$$= V_{GDn} - V_{GDn}+V_{GSn}$$
$$=V_{GSn}$$

Answer (score 0):

The statement written here is most likely:

\$V_{in} = V_{gs,n} = V_{gs,p} + V_{DD} \$

The minus should probably be an equality.

Remember that \$V_{gs,p}\$ is negative!